# Flutter call function of another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to call a function named `_callMe` from AlertDialog .

this is my example code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApplication());
}

class MainApplication extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApplication({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Training",
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<void> _callMe() async {
    print('Call Me ... !');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text("Open Modal"),
      onPressed: () => {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return SampleModal(callFunction: _callMe);
          },
        ),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SampleModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callFunction ;
  const SampleModal({Key? key, required this.callFunction}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          callFunction;
        },
        child: const Text("Call Me"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please explain to me what part of my code has problem ?

**UPDATE:**
I also changed function to this but still does not work:

```
void _callMe() {
    print('Call Me ... !');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
        onPressed: () {
          callFunction;
        },
```

with this:

```
        onPressed: () {
          callFunction();
        },
```

Comment: Can you describe on your answer what's different ?

Comment: The issue with the code is in the SampleModal widget. The onPressed method of the ElevatedButton is not calling the function correctly. Instead of calling the function using callFunction(), it's just referencing it using callFunction.